# Find locations in table that are within a certain radius distance of a given latitude/longitude

Tags: mysql, spatial

We have a table named areas with column - id, name, lattitude, longitude and position. The position column is of POINT type in MySQL and has latitude, longitude value.

To get areas within 25 kilometers of given latitude, longitude i.e. (28.638753, 77.073803) and order them based on proximity to this point, we are using the following query as recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator#findnearsql) by Google.

```
SELECT id, name, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(28.638753) ) * cos( radians( Lattitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians(77.073803) ) + sin( radians(28.638753) ) * sin( radians( Lattitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM areas 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance asc;
```

The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `areas` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Lattitude` decimal(18,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` decimal(18,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` point NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  SPATIAL KEY `sx_areas_position` (`position`)
)
```

The explain query gives following. Please note that rows = 21750 as it's test data. Actual data on production will be 100k+ rows.

[image]

Following is the index information:

[image]

This query is really slow when run with > 100k of records (takes up to 500 milliseconds). Is there any way to optimize it i.e.using spatial index?

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE cwmasterdb.areas;  and  SHOW INDEX FROM cwmasterdb.areas; and  EXPLAIN SELECT id, name, …..; so we can see what the optimizer chose for indexes to use for your query.  Someone will have suggestions for you.  Has the table had ANALYZE run on it recently  or   OPTIMIZE ?  My first suggestion would be from HAVING distance < 25  to  HAVING distance BETWEEN 0 and 25  could avoid table scan when you get rid of the 'less than' selection.

Comment: I have no clue what ANALYZE or OPTIMIZE is. Having distance between 0 and 25 gave no performance boost. I have shared all the info. Please let me know if you need further data.

Comment: did you mean to skip posting SHOW INDEX FROM areas:  ?  ANALYZE from 5.7 to consider using is documented here  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html
and OPTIMIZE from 5.7 that could be helpful is documented here 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: Done the edit. I didn't run ANALYZE or OPTIMIZE for this table.

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE is much different than your Google reference.  Look up in the link for their 'markers' table creation.  Their lattitude and longitude are probably better data types/sizes than what you have for performance and reducing data transfer volume.  No indexes were used according to EXPLAIN, I would think use of indexes would be beneficial.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: Any help how we can use indexes here?

Comment: Please add a tag of MySQL v.s so we know what version you are using.  Still digging for additional ways to reduce touching data.  Rick James's suggestion of a 'bounding box' will likely be a milestone for you.  Check out Rick's link to here on his first line, please.

Comment: This specific Question will probably be helpful for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438381/finding-nearest-places-using-point-datatype-and-st-distance-sphere-in-mysql-8

Comment: @WilsonHauck absolutely. i tried the same but getting just OK, no results. Here is the link I posted for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148381/mysql-using-st-distance-sphere-giving-ok-but-no-results

Comment: @WilsonHauck any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: I am still digging and my shovel is small.  It may be a few days before I understand 'bounding boxes'.

Comment: Here is a Question with Rick James's 'bounding box' example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956092/mysql-innodb-how-row-level-lock-on-composite-key-worked-in-simple-words/50205695#50205695  .  Get our table's LATTITUDE and LONGITUDE data type/sizes squared away to be like google.  Get a composite index on LATTITUDE and LONGITUDE for the WHERE to avoid your SCAN, please.  Check my profile, Network Profile and get in touch with me, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I discuss "bounding box" a little bit more in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) .  It is part of the buildup to a complex, but very fast, way I devised to "find the nearest".  (It pre-dates Spatial.)

Comment: @maverick  Hope you have reviewed the "bounding box" of Rick James's above.  You will find the WHERE to be your best friend for minimizing the time required to get within 25 Miles for your target zone.  Without the WHERE you will be facing MEGA wall clock TIME requirements on data tables the size you will be using in production.

Comment: See my answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/214353/2639

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of Q&A [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latitude-longitude+mysql).  As a first cut, use a "bounding box".

`ANALYZE TABLE` and `OPTIMIZE TABLE` are irrelevant.

You mention `Lattitude`, but you don't have such a column.

Either go with `point` and `SPATIAL`, or go with `latitude` and `longitude`; it is probably folly to mix them.

Comment: Sorry, I have latitude and longitude in my table. I have point too, it's basically duplicate info. Could you suggest anyway to optimize above query ?

Comment: @rickjames,  Please slow down before you indicate there is no column in their create table provided.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the spatial capabilities of MySQL?

That would look like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE ST_Distance(ST_Transform(position, [SRID]), ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('Point(28.638753 77.073803)', 4326)), [SRID]) < 25000
```

ST_GeomFromText() creates a point in space with your lat/lon coordinates. [SRID] is the EPSG code representing the geographic system used to place that point. 4326 is the conventional unprojected geographic system using the WGS84 datum (GPS works with this system).

Then you check for a certain distance with all the points in your table but you have to check with a [SRID] with meters unit. You would have to use a more or less local projection for that. In Eastern Quebec, I use 32198 or 32188 often. ST_Transform() projects your points into a system using meters as units if you use an appropriate SRID.

Note that it could be slow to process if you have a really large table of points since you have to transform every points in the table.

Answer (score 0):

## Use GIS

First,

1. Add a column `pt` which is `ST_SRID(ST_Point(longitude,latidue),4326)`
2. Drop your old `longitude` and `latidue` columns.
3. `CREATE SPATIAL INDEX spatidx ON areas (pt);`

Then do something like this,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(pt)
FROM areas
WHERE ST_Within(
  ST_Buffer( ST_SRID(ST_Point(77.073803,28.638753), 4326), 25000 ),
  pt
);
```